# How should SessionFactory instances be handled within (Spring MVC) web requests?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is a very basic question yet I need help. Suppose we make a singleton bean in spring, then spring ioc would make a single instance of that specific bean and when some sort of code needs it that would be injected.That's fine. But I am confused about how will it be managed by multi threading environment. Like if we make a sesssionFactory bean in spring as singleton then making many requests to a specific rest url which needs sessionFactory bean. How spring framework will provide that single instance of bean to that many requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about a persistence provider session factory, e.g. the [Hibernate SessionFactory](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)?

This factory should exist once for every DataSource, because it is not really cheap to create (connection handling, memory consumption) and should definitely be reused for the whole application lifetime, so a singleton is the way to go at this point. The factory is immutable (threadsafe) and there will be no concurrency issues.

Every incoming thread (created by a web request) should reuse this factory to create it's own session and this session should be used for this thread no matter how often it's accessed (e.g. stored in a thread local variable).

E.g. if we now move up in the abstraction layers to JPA level, the [JPA EntityManagerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) is wrapping the Hibernate SessionFactory and if you  want to use the JPA pendant to a Hibernate Session - the [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) - and you would like to let Spring manage it, you would get a EntityManager proxy like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

This would provide the EntityManager proxy (wrapped Session) for the current thread to your business code.

Same is valid for the next level of abstraction if you use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), it's repositories and `@Transactional` methods. In this case Spring also handles that for you.

Comment: Thank You..You explained it very well. Now I understand how SessionFactory is used as a singleton bean. But I also want to know, How a singleton bean (generated by @Component annotation) is used when concurrent web requests are made?

Comment: If it is a singleton (it's the default) it is of course shared by all threads. If it is your own Bean and it has a state (members) you have to care about thread safety / immutability. Otherwise you can have side effects / concurrency issues.

Comment: If I use a class very often, and this class have some local variables.Can I declare it as a bean and autowire it to every class where I need it without caring about concurrency issues?

Comment: If the methods of your bean only use local variables, yes. If the class has members, no, because the members are shared between threads. That is a general (Java) concurrency thing and it does matter how the singleton is created, not related to Spring / DI. Maybe try to start gaining more information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/